# How to create a make target for an unknown number of subdirectories?

Tags: makefile

I want to create a make target which builds all matching files in all nested subdirectories where the number of nested directories is unkown.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
outputfile-%.txt: $(wildcard somedirectory/**/%.xml)
    somecommand $< $@
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Should the `txt` file go into the same directory where the `xml` was, or where Make executes?

Comment: @Beta it should go in the directory where make executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting them all into the same directory as make is tricky.  Also note that if you ever have two different directories containing the same .xml file name, you will lose.

Something like this will work though.  There are other ways to do it, that don't involve the `include`, but require you to have a newer GNU make.  Note this relies on standard POSIX behavior when it comes to directory timestamps: if you want to do this on a non-POSIX-based system (e.g., Windows), you'll have to do something slightly different / less efficient:

(sorry, original was slightly busted: try this):

```
-include rules.mk

all: $(ALL_OUTPUTS)

DIRECTORIES := $(shell find -type d somedirectory)
rules.mk: $(DIRECTORIES)
    @for d in $(DIRECTORIES); do \
        for f in "$$d"/*.xml; do \
            echo "outputfile-$${f##*/}.txt: $$f"; \
            echo "ALL_OUTPUTS += outputfile-$${f##*/}.txt"; \
        done; \
     done > $@

outputfile-%.txt:
    somecommand $< $@
```